# Format text to 5 chars from a number

Tags: microsoft-access

In Access, I used a query to sum some numbers and appended the answer to another table (table 2). Now I need to export the number as string with five positions, but I can't seem to get it to hard code all five positions.

I have it formatted as text, field length 5, custom format "`00000`" (I also tried `@@@@@`).  Example:  `3 + 3 + 1 = 7`. Then append the `7` to table 2.  It always shows as 7. How do I make it show as `00007`?

Answer (score 3):

In Access, do it as in this query:

```
SELECT aTable.aNumber, Format([aNumber],"00000") AS yourNumber FROM aTable;
```